# Наложение непрозрачной области изображения с помощью CSS

Tags: html, css, svg

Меня интересует динамическое изменение изображения с прозрачным фоном и достижение этого с помощью CSS.
Что мне действительно нужно, так это создать своего рода силуэт, чтобы ко всем непрозрачным пикселям был применен цвет. В данном случае Black.

До и после должны выглядеть примерно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обратите внимание, что у обоих изображений прозрачный фон.

Есть ли метод, который можно использовать для этого с помощью CSS?

Если нет, есть ли простой способ создать силуэт и переключаться между двумя изображениями на стороне клиента в контексте веб-страницы?

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Overlay non-transparent area of image with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32770808/7394871) от участника  [@Selfish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3873012/selfish).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/32770808/7394871

Answer (score 3):

Подобного эффекта можно добиться с помощью фильтров webkit:

```
img {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -webkit-filter: contrast(0%);
    -webkit-filter: brightness(0%);
}

img:hover {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
    -webkit-filter: contrast(100%);
    -webkit-filter: brightness(100%);
}
```

```css
img {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -webkit-filter: contrast(0%);
    -webkit-filter: brightness(0%);
}

img:hover {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
    -webkit-filter: contrast(100%);
    -webkit-filter: brightness(100%);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZw5u.png" alt="">
```

Обратите внимание, что [этот метод поддерживается не всеми браузерами](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters). Для поддержки IE вы можете установить это как фоновое изображение и изменять его при наведении курсора.

---

### Использование двух изображений для лучшей совместимости с браузером

Если вы хотите использовать два изображения, вы можете добиться того же эффекта с гораздо более широкой поддержкой браузера, просто поменяв изображение местами при наведении курсора. Что-то вроде этого:

```
div {
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pmz7l.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

div:hover {
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZw5u.png');
}
```

```css
img {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -webkit-filter: contrast(0%);
    -webkit-filter: brightness(0%);
}

img:hover {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
    -webkit-filter: contrast(100%);
    -webkit-filter: brightness(100%);
}

div {
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pmz7l.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

div:hover {
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZw5u.png');
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZw5u.png" alt=""></img>
<div></div>
```

### Улучшенный пример, поддерживающий все цвета

Это решение требует немного больше работы, но поддерживает все цвета, а не только черный!

```css
img {
    -webkit-filter: url(#monochrome);
    filter:  url(#monochrome);
}

img:hover {
    filter: none;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZw5u.png" alt=""></img>
<svg>
  <filter id="monochrome" type="matrix" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
    <feColorMatrix type="matrix"
      values="0 0 0 0 0.6588
              0 0 0 0 0.4745
              0 0 0 0 0.1686
              0 0 0 1 0" />
  </filter>
</svg>
```

Вот важные моменты:

В этом методе используется , в основном расширенная функция для определения ваших собственных фильтров. Здесь я свел все цветовые каналы к нулю (все нули для первых четырех столбцов), а затем добавил к ним постоянное значение, которое мне было нужно (это последний столбец). Убедитесь, что в теге  указан type = "matrix", а в теге  задается color-interpolation-filters = "sRGB", иначе матрица будет интерпретироваться по-разному.

Эти сообщения были очень полезны, если вы хотите узнать больше:

https://alistapart.com/article/finessing-fecolormatrix

https://css-tricks.com/color-filters-can-turn-your-gray-skies-blue/

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32770922/7394871) от участника  [@pgruber](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4505086/pgruber).</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Решение с помощью `canvas`. Загруженное изображение отрисовывается на двух неотображаемых холстах: `canvas1` - как есть, `canvas2` - только силуэт. Цвет силуэта определен константой `COLOR`, а источник изображения с прозрачным фоном - `IMG_SRC`.

```js
const COLOR = 'rgb(45,165,30)';
const IMG_SRC = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZw5u.png';

let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let w,h;
canvas.addEventListener('mouseover', showFace);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseleave', hideFace);

let canvas1 = document.createElement('canvas');
let ctx1 = canvas1.getContext('2d');

let canvas2 = document.createElement('canvas');
let ctx2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');

let img = new Image();
img.src = IMG_SRC;
img.addEventListener('load', drawImage);

function drawImage(e){
    let image = e.path[0];
    w = canvas.width = canvas1.width = canvas2.width = image.naturalWidth;
    h = canvas.height = canvas1.height = canvas2.height = image.naturalHeight;
    
    ctx1.drawImage(image,0,0);
    
    ctx2.drawImage(image,0,0);
    ctx2.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-in';
    ctx2.fillStyle = COLOR;
    ctx2.fillRect(0,0,w,h);
    
    ctx.drawImage(canvas2,0,0);
}

function showFace(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h);
    ctx.drawImage(canvas1,0,0);
}

function hideFace(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h);
    ctx.drawImage(canvas2,0,0);
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: наверное согласишься, что на SVG это сделать намного проще, чем в canvas. Ответ конечно очень полезен для разработчиков в canvas Для некоторого усложнения сможешь добавить какую-нибудь анимацию, любую, на твой вкус

Comment: Зато какой цвет))) Вообще я хотел по-другому сделать: перебрать данные изображения и попиксельно преобразовать в нужный цвет если есть цветность пикселя, но по ходу работы резко обленился))) Код может быть гораздо проще, но я следовал рекомендациям и отрисовал все на разных холстах, потом только подставляю результат. Это быстро и эффективно.  Конечно, для этой задачи больше подходит вариант с фильтрами, ведь можно по сути задать правила CSS всем изображениям, а мне придется переделывать код и плодить множество теневых холстов. Тогда нужен вариант с перерисовкой одного собственного холста.

Answer (score 1):

Мне хотелось бы, в связи [с крайним примером из ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1309648/28748),  немного остановиться на анализе возможностей фильтра SVG feColormatrix

Ниже схема, объясняющая значения параметров этого фильтра из статьи [Finessing `feColorMatrix`](https://alistapart.com/article/finessing-fecolormatrix/) написанная [**Una Kravets**](https://alistapart.com/author/unakravets/)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из схемы становится понятно, что зелёный цвет силуэта получится при установке значения во вторую строку (канал **G**)

```css
img {
    -webkit-filter: url(#monochrome);
    filter:  url(#monochrome);
}

img:hover {
    filter: none;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZw5u.png" alt=""></img>

<svg>
  <filter id="monochrome" type="matrix" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
    <feColorMatrix type="matrix"
      values="0 0 0 0 0
              0 0 0 0 0.7
              0 0 0 0 0
              0 0 0 1 0" />
  </filter>
</svg>
```

Красный цвет получается при установке значения канала **R**  1 строка, 4 столбец

```css
img {
    -webkit-filter: url(#monochrome);
    filter:  url(#monochrome);
}

img:hover {
    filter: none;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZw5u.png" alt=""></img>

<svg>
  <filter id="monochrome" type="matrix" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
    <feColorMatrix type="matrix"
      values="0 0 0 0 1
              0 0 0 0 0
              0 0 0 0 0
              0 0 0 1 0" />
  </filter>
</svg>
```

Смешивание каналов: **R+B** - пурпурный цвет

```css
img {
    -webkit-filter: url(#monochrome);
    filter:  url(#monochrome);
}

img:hover {
    filter: none;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZw5u.png" alt=""></img>

<svg>
  <filter id="monochrome" type="matrix" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
    <feColorMatrix type="matrix"
      values="0 0 0 0 1
              0 0 0 0 0
              0 0 0 0 1
              0 0 0 1 0" />
  </filter>
</svg>
```

> В следующем примере мы повторно используем матрицу из примера
> пурпурного и добавляем 100% альфа-канал на синем уровне. Мы сохраняем
> красные значения, но переопределяем любой красный цвет в тенях,
> поэтому все цвета теней становятся синими, а самые светлые значения, в
> которых есть красный цвет, становятся смесью синего и красного
> (пурпурного).

```css
img {
    -webkit-filter: url(#monochrome);
    filter:  url(#monochrome);
}

img:hover {
    filter: none;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZw5u.png" alt=""></img>

<svg>
  <filter id="monochrome" type="matrix" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
    <feColorMatrix type="matrix"
      values="1 0 0 0 0
              0 0 0 0 0
              0 0 1 1 0
              0 0 0 1 0" />
  </filter>
</svg>
```

> Если бы это последнее значение было меньше 0 (до -1), произошло бы
> обратное. Тени станут красными, а не синими. При -1 они создают
> идентичные эффекты:

```css
img {
    -webkit-filter: url(#monochrome);
    filter:  url(#monochrome);
}

img:hover {
    filter: none;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZw5u.png" alt=""></img>

<svg>
  <filter id="monochrome" type="matrix" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
    <feColorMatrix type="matrix"
      values="1 0 0 0 0
              0 0 0 0 0
              0 0 1 -1 0
              0 0 0 1 0" />
  </filter>
</svg>
```

Мы можем повлиять на общую альфа отдельных каналов через четвертую строку.
В примере ниже убирается красный канал. 4 строка 1 столбец **-2** (убираются красные оттенки лица)

```css
img {
    -webkit-filter: url(#monochrome);
    filter:  url(#monochrome);
}

img:hover {
    filter: none;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZw5u.png" alt=""></img>

<svg>
  <filter id="monochrome" type="matrix" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
    <feColorMatrix type="matrix"
      values="1 0 0 0 0
              0 1 0 0 0
              0 0 1 0 0
              -2 0 0 1 0" />
  </filter>
</svg>
```

**GRAYSCALE**

```css
img {
    -webkit-filter: url(#monochrome);
    filter:  url(#monochrome);
}

img:hover {
    filter: none;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZw5u.png" alt=""></img>

<svg>
  <filter id="monochrome" type="matrix" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
    <feColorMatrix type="matrix"
      values="1 0 0 0 0
              1 0 0 0 0
              1 0 0 0 0
              0 0 0 1 0" />
  </filter>
</svg>
```